# Why does centre of mass formula always lead to a vector joining origin to com point for whichever origin that one may choose?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, mathematical-physics

A simple question that I had from long, the position vector from an origin to the centre of mass is given as $ \frac{ \int \vec{r} \rho dV}{M}$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector to the mass element of the body and $M$ is the total mass of the body.

Centre of mass itself is a location on a body which exists without reference to coordinates i.e: a truly geometrical point.

But, What exactly in the mathematical structure in the formula to evaluate the vector to com causes it always to be a vector joining the chosen origin to the actual geometrical com point in space?

I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: You could ask the same thing about the position of a point mass.  "The position of a mass exists without reference to coordinates.  Why is it always a vector joining the chosen origin to the actual position of the mass in space?"  Do you find this to be a paradox as well?

Comment: I don't find it to be a paradox, I am simply asking why it evaluates to the same geometrical point in all coordinate system. As in, what part of the mathematics allows for this to happen @MichaelSeifert

Comment: My point was that it seems like this is a property of *any* position vector, not just the COM vector.  Is the COM vector in some way special for your argument?

Comment: The position vector $\vec r$ in the formula joins the mass element to the origin, so the mean position vector (position of COM) will also join the COM to the origin. What do you think about that?

Comment: Right indeed, in any coordinate the position vectors will point to the geometrical points. Yes, there is nothing special to center of mass here except the context.

Comment: I'm looking for a mathematical proof @Tofi

Comment: You mean that you want to know why evaluating the formula always results in the same point, regardless of the chosen origin?

Comment: It's a pretty simple calculation: given an origin $O$ choose another alternative origin $O'=O+v$. Then $r'=r-v$. Now use linearity of the integral to find that the COM in new coordinates is just the one in old coordinates minus $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a body in space, and let's consider two frames of reference: $R$ with origin $O$ and $R'$ with origin $O'$. The position of the center of mass in frame $R$ is by definition:
$$\vec r_{COM} = \frac{1}{M}\int\vec rdM.$$
Then, in frame $R'$, the position of center of mass is
\begin{align}
\vec r'_{COM} &= \frac{1}{M}\int\vec r'dM \\
&= \frac{1}{M}\int(\vec{O'O}+\vec r)dM \\
&= \vec{O'O} + \frac{1}{M}\int\vec rdM \\
&= \vec{O'O}+\vec r_{COM},
\end{align}
which is a vector joining $O'$ to the same "geometrical point" we found in frame $R$. I don't know if you would consider this to be a proof honestly.

Comment: This was much simpler than I had thought it to be. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's fine by me if it makes you happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the centre-of-mass formula,

$$\vec r_\text{com}=\frac{ \int \vec{r} \rho \,\mathrm dV}{M}=\frac{ \int \vec{r}\, \mathrm dm}{M},$$

the position vector $\vec r$, which you are integrating through, i.e. adding up for all points in the object, is defined as pointing from the origin of the arbitrarily chosen coordinate system. Thus the position resulting vector will also start from the origin.

Why having such origin? Well, in what other way can we point out a position? Sure, an object exists regardless of any such arbitrary coordinate system's origin. But how will you tell me where it is without some kind of reference?

Mathematics is the "language" we use throughout physics. A position vector is nothing but a human-made invention, a method in this language to communicate where something is. It is impossible to point out a location in space without reference to an origin, a coordinate system. Whomever invented the above formula has chosen the zero-point of this coordinate system as the reference. Because why not - this seems to be the simplest general choice.